# asking for help fixing a broken promise chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, chain

Here is the promise chain. I feel like it looks ok but it isn't working like I want it to. I've looked it over and everything seems in order. Being new to this, do I just repeat `poem` in every new iteration of `.then`? I am making it to the `.catch` because it prints out "something went wrong" I would love any advice!

```
let poem = 'But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer'

const poemJudge = (poem) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(poem.length > 25){
                console.log('We need to review this poem further');
                resolve(poem);
            } else {
                reject('woah what? way too elementary');
            }
        }, generateRandomDelay());
    });
};

const keepThinking = (resolvedPoem) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(resolvedPoem.length < 45) {
                console.log('terse, but we must deliberate further');
                resolve(resolvedPoem);
            } else {
                reject('seriously? the poem is way too long!');
            }
        }, generateRandomDelay())

    });
};

const KeepOnThinking = (secondResolvedPoem) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(secondResolvedPoem < 40 && secondResolvedPoem > 30) {
                console.log('Nailed it')
                resolve(secondResolvedPoem);
            } else {
                reject('you are top 50 at least')
            }
        }, generateRandomDelay());
    });
};


poemJudge(poem)
.then((resolvedPoem) => {
    return keepThinking(resolvedPoem);
})
.then((secondResolvedPoem) => {
    return keepOnThinking(secondResolvedPoem);
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('you have completed the poem challenge');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log('something went wrong');
});
```

Comment: It's a good idea to log the error that is passed to `catch`. In this case the error is `something went wrong ReferenceError: generateRandomDelay is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the method generateRandomDelay defined in your code.

When you call reject(), a promise fails and it's caught in a .catch block.
In this example, the poem's length is > 25 and < 45 so:

1. poemJudge resolves it
2. keepThinking rejects it
3. your catch block catches the rejection.

You can confirm this by logging the message (err) you get in the catch block:

```
poemJudge(poem)
.then((resolvedPoem) => {
    return keepThinking(resolvedPoem);
})
.then((secondResolvedPoem) => {
    return keepOnThinking(secondResolvedPoem);
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('you have completed the poem challenge');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Your console will print:

> We need to review this poem further
>
> seriously? the poem is way too long!

Comment: I can confirm this. `keepThinking()` rejects your promise and that takes your flow to `catch()`.